# AWS: pdf file uploaded to S3 is blank

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, sftp

I read a pdf file via `sFTP` and then upload it to S3. When I download the file from S3 and open it in a pdf viewer, it's a blank document. The file size on `sFTP` is 40kb, but on S3, it's 80kb.

This is how I download via sftp:

```js
sftp.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8', (error, content) => {
  if (error) throw error;
  conn.end();
  resolve(content);
});
```

And this is how I upload to S3:

```js
const uploadParams = {
  Bucket: bucket, Key: '', Body: '', ContentType: 'application/pdf'
};

uploadParams.Body = content;
uploadParams.Key = fileAttributes.s3Location;

logger.debug('Uploading to S3', uploadParams);
// call S3 to retrieve upload file to specified bucket
try {
  const stored = await s3.putObject(uploadParams).promise();
  logger.info('Upload Success', stored);
} catch (err) {
  logger.error('S3 upload error', err);
  throw err;
}
```

Perhaps something is wrong with the encoding being used?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to remove the encoding. It seems to be auto detected correctly and the file contents are visible in S3. Changed to this:

```js
sftp.readFile(filePath, (error, buffer) => {
  if (error) throw error;
  conn.end();
  resolve(buffer);
});
```